# How do I pass a selected value to an anonymous function within an observable array?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am attempting to pass the selected value from a `select option binding` to a computed observable array but getting an `undefined` error: Can I access this value with in the view model?

I need to pass the selected value `(ArtistId)` so that I can display data from the album list:

If I simply hard-code a value, it works.

Example:

```
    self.albumList = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(discography(), function (item) {

            // Pass Selected Artist ID here instead of hard coding.

            return item.ArtistId === '1';

        });
    });
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4djkngfy/):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computed observable can access any other observable. So you need to access the `selectedArtist` observable:

```
self.albumList = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.selectedArtist()) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.discography(), function (item) {
            return item.ArtistId === self.selectedArtist().ArtistId;
        });
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4djkngfy/2/

Comment: Hey Michael: I tried the similar solution but did not use an if statement. When I remove the if statement, it does not work. However, it works with `if` included. Can you tell me why? Just need to understand how this works. Thanks!!

Comment: In your example, `selectedArtist` isn't set initially. It's set by the `value` binding, which happens during `ko.applyBindings`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!